# NSIS Uninstaller Permission Level

Tags: windows, nsis, uninstallation

I have an NSIS installer script that generates an Uninstaller. The Uninstaller, when created, requires elevated permissions in order to be executed. Certain  requirements make it such that I need to be able to run the uninstaller as any user without the elevated permission level. None of the other files that are generated are set with elevated permissions, not even the application executable itself. Is there any way to set the permission level to any user? Here is my NSIS script. I have removed a lot from the script so that the application stays anonymous, but have left everything that I think is relevant

```
Function .onInit
    UserInfo::GetAccountType
    pop $0
    ${If} $0 != "admin"
        MessageBox mb_iconstop "Administrator rights required!"
        SetErrorLevel 740 ;ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED
        Quit
    ${EndIf}

    ${IfNot} ${AtLeastWin7}
      MessageBox MB_OK "Application requires at minimum Windows 7 as the installed operating system. Exiting installation..."
      Quit
    ${EndIf}

    IntOp $0 ${SF_SELECTED} | ${SF_RO}
    SectionSetFlags ${SecApp} $0
FunctionEnd

; sections
Section "AppSection" SecApp
    ... installer stuff
    WriteRegStr HKCU "${AppRegistryPath}" \
                     "UninstallString" "$\"$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe$\""

    WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"
    ... more installer stuff
SectionEnd

Section "Uninstall"
    ; code that terminates the running application

    ; code that removes a firewall rule

    DetailPrint "Removing files and directories"
    Delete "$INSTDIR\*"
    Delete "$INSTDIR\x86\*"
    Delete "$INSTDIR\x64\*"
    Delete "$INSTDIR\fonts\*"
    RMDir "$INSTDIR\x86"
    RMDir "$INSTDIR\x64"
    RMDir "$INSTDIR\fonts"
    RMDir "$INSTDIR"

    DetailPrint "Removing registry values"
    DeleteRegKey HKCU "${AppRegistryPath}"
    DeleteRegKey HKCU "${AppPath}"
    DeleteRegKey HKLM "${AppRegistryPath}"
    DeleteRegKey HKLM "${AppPath}"
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

The uninstaller uses the same manifest as the installer and the UAC part of the manifest is set by `RequestExecutionLevel`.

You could try using `RequestExecutionLevel highest`, it will only elevate administrators, normal users will run the application normally without any prompts. Use `UserInfo::GetAccountType` in `un.onInit` and abort with a error message if you need to be elevated.

You can also re-launch yourself and request elevation with `ExecShell "RunAs" '"$ExePath"'` (you still need to verify with `UserInfo::GetAccountType`).

Comment: `RequestExecutionLevel highest` did not work. The uninstaller still wants elevated privileges. Not sure what you mean by the second statement `re-launch yourself and request elevation`

Comment: "RequestExecutionLevel highest" will request elevation from administrators but that is not a problem since HKCU and $AppData will be correct. If you don't want administrators to elevate by default either then you must use "RequestExecutionLevel user". If you are running non-elevated and you find out that you need to elevate (unless I'm not understanding your question?) can be done with the RunAs verb.

Comment: ...or is your problem that you never want elevation but Windows 10 forces elevation on you even with  "RequestExecutionLevel user"?

Comment: I have an installer in which I need elevated permissions. On the installer launch, I'm checking to make sure the user has admin rights otherwise, I notify them. I'm doing a lot of things such as adding firewall rules, adding registry values, etc... But for the uninstaller, I do not want the uninstall.exe file to have elevated permissions.

Comment: That makes no sense to me, you would need to elevate the uninstaller to undo the things you did in the installer.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [UAC plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/UAC_plug-in). Among other things, it allows you to control when in your script elevation is requested, so you can have the uninstall section skip over doing that.

Comment: So, in my case, I'm running elevated but for one specific area(the uninstaller), I want to run as a non-admin. Does the UAC plugin do that? The example I see is elevating the user to admin, it seems

Answer (score 1):

With Windows Vista or above, the correct way to mark a program is to embed an application manifest within your application that tells the operating system what the application needs. There are attributes within this application manifest that permit developers to specify their programs level of execution or `requested execution level`.

The request level options are as follows:

- **As Invoker** – The application runs with the same access token as the
  parent process. (Recommended for standard user applications)
- **Highest Available** – The application runs with the highest privileges the
  current user can obtain. (Recommended for mixed-mode applications)
- **Require Administrator** – The application runs only for administrators
  and requires that the application be launched with the full access
  token of an administrator. (Recommended for administrator only
  applications)
- **No Execution Level Information** – The application does
  not have an embeded `request execution level` manifest.

> Unless an application is designed to be run exclusively by system administrators, it should be run with the least privileges possible.

#### No Execution Level

On Windows Vista and above, when no execution level information is set in the application's manifest and the application is not elevated previously the application runs in *legacy mode* for backwards compatibility support. In this mode the operating system uses a virtualization mechanism for the file system and registry to access. This means that its attempt to create or change files in restricted folder locations or to write in registry restricted hives is redirected (reflected) towards a "per-user" accessible location. See [VirtualStore](http://softables.tk/docs/getting-started/virtualstore) for more information on how this applies here.

**More information on this subject can be found here:**
[Windows User Account Control](http://softables.tk/docs/advanced/uac)

---

On the page I linked above (Windows User Account Control) is a link in which you can download some manifests with these `request execution level` attributes inside xml files. In your case I'd edit one of them with your desired level of execution. Using the following snippet of code this can be done:

```nsis
Section "Uninstall"
    !define RequestLevel User
    !define ResHacker    `${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Manifests\ResHacker.exe`
    !define ManifDir     `${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Manifests`
    !define Manifest     `NSIS_2.46_Win8`
    !packhdr             `$%TEMP%\exehead.tmp` `"${Reshacker}" -addoverwrite "%TEMP%\exehead.tmp", "%TEMP%\exehead.tmp", "${ManifDir}\${Manifest}_${RequestLevel}.manifest", 24,1,1033`
    
    # The rest of your code...
SectionEnd
```

All the required files you need is in the downloadable zip file at the bottom of the aforementioned webpage. How to use this is also explained in greater detail.

**NOTE**: Although I agree with Anders as you need elevated privileges to delete `HKLM` keys, mess with the firewall settings, etc.

Comment: I think all of these responses are good but in my case, I need to just remove the uninstaller entirely. I am building a .NET Win32 application that also is using the Desktop Bridge Converter to deploy the application to the Windows 10 app store. In order for the application to get approved, it cannot run anything at an elevated permission level. Since I need to be able to remove registry keys, etc... I have to have elevated permissions on the uninstaller in the Win32 environment. But as a Windows 10 app, the uninstall is taken care of for me and uses a virtual registry.